# can't replay android support library v4

Tags: android, android-support-library

i have a facebook sdk.

i import the facebook skd which has a libs folder which has a support v4 jar file **which size is 345kb**.

i have to support the navigation bar in my 2.2 android so i must import android support -v7 appcompat libarary, which contains a libs folder which has a support v4 jar file **which size is 544kb**.

these two jar files have different has sha 1 so i want to copy the begest one instead of the other.

i go to facebook sdk folder and replaced the old jar which the better one. then i refresh the eclpse. then i clean all project.

but ecipse keep tell me that these two jars don't have the same hash sha1 although i copied them.

i went to the property of the facebook sdk library and checked the property of the support v4 jar but the size still the size of the old jar which i already replaced.

i tried to remove the facebook skd then re import it but still the same problem

what should i do to make these two jars the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add again Android Support-v4 library in both projects (Facebook SDK and Android Support-v7 AppCompat) via Eclipse context menu:

```
Android Tools > Add support library...
```